# Should I use serialization to store data in a sql server?

Tags: php, sql, database, serialization, content-management-system

I am working on a small CMS for personal usage and I am wondering what the best way to store data is. I have looked at a couple of different options and right now serialization of classes seems very attractive. I am considering the following code for serialization and unserialization. The object's I would be serializing would include things such as Content, Users, and Options.

```
$str = base64_encode( serialize( $object ) );
$object = unserialize( base64_decode( $str ) );
```

Eventually these classes will store large amounts of data such as entire posts. Is this a decent practice for storing large amounts of data?

Also, what database structure would you recommend if I did this?

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM to handle it?

Comment: No, if you want to be able to easily search and select data you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it is not the way to go. You are going to lose ability to index your data on DMBS level, also debugging becomes really hard. This is also going to break your application when you change your classes - migration between different versions becomes problematic. You are better off using proper database structure with somekind of ORM framework.